# Nativescript emulator installation headaches

Tags: android, android-emulator, nativescript

I've been trying to get emulators to work for NativeScript on my brand new clean Windows 10 laptop for three days and nothing is working.

To be more accurate, I think I was able to get the 'emulator-5554' to launch, but it doesn't not load the Groceries app.

I have all the Angular requirements installed since I also build Angular SPAs and they work fine.  I read and followed all these articles, and I still can't get emulators to work.

I even installed GenyMotion, but it is not detected. I have not installed Android Studio since I'll be developing with Visual Studio Code, so I used the Android CLI to install the SDK.

https://docs.nativescript.org/start/general-requirements

https://docs.nativescript.org/start/introduction

https://docs.nativescript.org/start/cli-basics

https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/android-virtual-devices?_ga=2.188319272.1221867054.1547512018-618552819.1547075699

https://docs.nativescript.org/start/quick-setup

https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-win - this was my primary emulator setup

I have also read many SO posts and none have solved my problem.

Is there some documentation somewhere that is simple and clear, with step by step instructions on how to get emulators installed that will work with Nativescript?  What am I missing?

*BTW, when I connect my Samsung Galaxy S8 Active phone to my laptop, it's not recognized by the `tns device` command either.*

*I can't believe it's this difficult to get emulators to work.  I also can't believe that the Nativescript documentation has left this information out of their instructions.*

Comment: I have always used Android Studio to have the emulators installed properly. Using command "tns doctor" would ideally get the environment ready if any of the environment is not properly setup. After setup recommended to reboot. Some times we need to make Android emulator setup with Cold Boot option.

Comment: Does your adb commands work? If you run `adb devices`, does that give you list of emulators / device?

Comment: @Baskar ````tns doctor```` returns all green.  Everything shows as being successfully installed.  I've also rebooted several times.  I'll keep checking.

Comment: @Manoj stupid question, do I need to run ````adb devices```` just inside the folder with my application, or can it be anywhere on the system?  Also, do the emulators need to be attempted to be started, or not?  When I run the command from anywhere in the command prompt without the emulators running, I get the message: "List of devices attached", with no results.

Comment: The emulator must be running when you run this command. And yes, you can run it from anywhere. You could start genymotion emulator and see if adb lists that.

Comment: Ok, I opened GenyMotion but got an error popup that says, "Your CPU is incompatible with virtualization technologies."  What the heck?  This is a 2017 Dell Latitude laptop.  I also got an error when running ````tns run android````, that says, "The package manager service found that the device didn't have enough storage space to install the app...".  Again, new laptop, over 350GB free!

Comment: Sorry I meant 2019 Dell Laptop.

Comment: @KingWilder You would need to install Intel HAXM if it is not installed. Ideally most problems with emulator will be resolved if you have Android Studio installed.For the memory check the memory allocation in device settings. Also use cold boot. Start emulator from Android AVD Manager and then try from Nativescript.

Comment: @Baskar I'll install Android Studio and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Does anyone have a good solution to this yet? I am in the same boat. `$abd devices` outputs nothing, while `sudo ./avdmanager list avd` outputs a device I created, but Nativescript Sidekick says "No android emulator images found" after restart, too. Sidekick also cannot see my OnePlus when USB cabled to the PC, developer mode activated. I'm on Linux (Xubuntu 19.04) and don't want a 5GB Android Studio on my PC just to run an emulator in another software.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer most are looking for, but this is what was wrong with my installation and this is how I fixed it:

1. I noticed that the docs all had `$./advmanager [someArg]` and I had to be *sudo* for commands to execute. So I ran `sudo chown -R myUser:myUser /usr/local/android` thus changing all owner:group permissions *from* root to myUser.
2. then I could run `./avdmanager create....` (full command below) without having to be superuser
3. restarted Nativescript Sidekick

I know this is kinda stupid, but I worked out that if the AVD was created as root, the Sidekick program running as myUser could not see and access it. This was confirmed when I ran `avdmanager list avd` as sudo and got a result, but after changing my files' ownership from root to myUser, nothing was listed from the same command.
I recreated my virtual devices (AVDs) as a normal user and Sidekick was able to see them.

edit: the actual line I ran to create the AVD (because I see a lot of variation in these):

```
$ ./avdmanager create avd --name Pixel -k "system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86" --device "pixel"?
```

The uppercase and lowercase "pixel"s come from one entry from the output of
`$./avdmanager list`

```
id: 17 or "pixel"
    Name: Pixel
    OEM : Google
---------
```

Do this "create" step for each device you want to emulate.

Comment: It seems I do need to install Android Studio.  When I did, my emulator worked.  I guess this is Ok, I just didn't want the overhead on my system since I was never going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Install Android Studio and open it. Then (without starting a new project) click on:

`Configure` --> `AVD Manager`.

There you can create virtual devices, which will be recodnized by NativeScript Sidekick and its virtual device launcher.